# Who, the subject or the object of the main clause, does the subject pronoun of a subordinate clause refer to?

Tags: pronouns, subordinate-clauses

It goes as follows in an un-manipulated text about websites serving as social networks:

> They are sweepingly putting many users on the brink of
>   addiction, if they are not already victims of it.

[To ask my question and to clarify, changes are made below :]

> They [ = social networks] are sweepingly putting many users on the brink of
>   addiction, if ***they*** [ = users inclined to addiction] are not already victims of it.

Considering that the if clause is set out to mean  **possibly, some *users* are addicted already**, the question is:

Does ***they*** **[ = users inclined to addiction]** possibly put readers off the clarity of the whole text, since it sounds to refer to the subject **They ( = social networks)** rather than **many users**.How do you feel about this?

One second thing:

How would it sound if we leave out the second **they**? :

> They are sweepingly putting many users on the brink of addiction, if
>   not already victims of it.

hoping i have been clear enough, many many thanks.

Comment: I think you are quite right that this is very poor sentence design, and you have explained why pretty thoroughly and well. (I would add that "sweepingly" is an odd choice for the adverb here.) Your proposed emendation, leaving out the second "they," *sounds* OK but makes the original problem even worse, in terms of requiring us to reread before we can figure out it applies to the object not the subject of the main clause. A better fix might pick up on the idea of *brink* thus: "They are drawing many users to the brink of addiction and have pushed some over it."

Comment: Thank you, Brian. I loved your clean-cut suggestion; (drawing, push over)

Comment: The antecedent of 'it' should perhaps be taken as 'the brink of extinction' here; I'd write 'They are irresponsibly putting many users on the brink of addiction (those who are not already there).'

Comment: Hadn't noticed that.
(Oh my goodness. I'll be doomed in my IELTS exam if the evaluators are this particular!)

Comment: phenry, this is not exactly addressing our topic here. But I learnt a lot from it.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I had taken it the same way (glad I wasn't just imagining it).  I would perhaps alter it to say something like, "They are sweepingly putting many users on the brink of addiction, if they are not already **there**."  'There' would mean 'on the brink of addiction'. I would appreciate your take on this, please.

Comment: @Romulus Parthus: Fine. And an extended (spatial) metaphor! I'm not sure I'd use 'sweepingly' here; as I hinted above, I think that the 'cavalier' attitude of the social networks may be what is intended to be stressed. I may be wrong. Perhaps 'sweepingly putting' sounds incongruous. "They are sweeping many users to the brink of addiction, if they are not already there" may be better.

Comment: @Edwin; You know, in my mother tongue there is an idiom that might be best translated as: "to beat every one with the same stick"; that is to say, with no distinctions taken into account. Turning to our case here,by sweepingly I meant more or less,the same thing. I'd be grateful to know if it sits well in the sentence, seen in that regard.

Comment: It just doesn't sound right (other native speakers might disagree). 'Sweeping' is often used for statements with the meaning you give. We'd probably use 'They are railroading many users to the brink of addiction ....'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ; I'm learning lots of things from you. (also liked your profile)

Answer (score 0):

Everything about this sentence is bad. :)

- **sweepingly** is a distractingly weird adverb
- **the brink of addiction** is a weird mixed metaphor. Addiction doesn't really have a brink. (Googling turns up thousands of hits, but they're low quality English as far as I can tell).
- **victims of [addiction]** is another ungainly phrase. One is normally the victim of the actions of someone else - not one's own illness, foible, etc. It sounds like the phrase is really trying to say "victim of manipulative behaviour" or something, but getting tangled up.

and, of course the switch in referent for "it".

IMHO the whole sentence is already unclear and hard to parse, and it's hard to tell how much this particular flaw contributes to that.

A much clearer rephrasing would be:

> They are pushing many users close to the brink of addiction, or beyond.